# Safe to use Chicken Manure in my compost?

Tags: compost, manure

I was talking to someone about adding chicken manure to my compost and they said that I shouldn't do it because it's dangerous.  I had assumed that as long as I let is compost for 6 months to a year everything would be ok.

Who is right here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right. It's generally accepted that chicken manure is a fine addition to compost, with the caveat that, as you mention, it should cure for 6-12 months. Chicken manure is high in nitrogen, and if you have a good mix of "browns", it will help the pile get hot quickly.

I regularly add small amounts of poultry manure (from about 2 dozen birds) to my pile of horse manure and stall bedding, and it makes excellent compost.

Answer (score 2):

http://seattletilth.org/learn/resources-1/city-chickens/compostingchickenmanure

Is a really awesome site with lots of information about the process. If you read it through you will have a much better understanding and realize the important steps in the process you should take instead of jump pouring a pile on your pile.  But I do highly recommend it!

Comment: Please summarize a bit more information from the site. We'd prefer the only valuable content of a post not be a link as links tend to die.